# Fell the phylogenetic tree

Tags: technology, evolution, humans, mutation

A top secret organization is planning to introduce a New World Order and replaces every human being (homo sapiens sapiens) with the evolved form of sub species of homo sapiens. Meaning we are sub species of homo sapiens same apply for the Neanderthal and many other extinct species.

The secret organization deemed homo sapiens sapiens as a threat to Earth and its inhabitants, no other periods in pre/history have the world witnessed so much destruction to the environment and causes that drive many animals to extinctions except the recent millennium when human pollutes the land, sea and air.

The west have pioneered many decades long projects to map our DNA and our brain, the secret organization decided it's time to commence Project Homo Sapiens Illuminati replacing Homo Sapiens Sapiens in 1000 years aka millennium kingdom.

My question is using DNA splicing can we introduce another sub species of human? or are there any method to accelerate the branching of our phylogenetic tree within 10 centuries?

Note: I didn't have time to verify facts comment below if there are mistakes in my OP

Comment: Is Obama behind this?

Comment: How different do you want this newly evolved species to be?  It's one thing to methodically breed out a trait or whatever; another thing entirely to be unable to procreate with *Homo sapiens sapiens*?

Comment: @Mikey good question I need to discuss with them our meeting is planned on Mars in 2025 AD, can you wait?

Comment: @user6760 - sure; I intend to be living on Mars by then, so it should be a short commute; but my planner only goes to the end of this calendar year, so remind me.

Comment: @Mikey depends on weather condition and Mars One maybe you can tagged along on Mars Two, people must be able to tell a homo sapiens illuminati from other species.

Comment: ....I can't answer this question as written, I feel like your using the idea of evolution wrong, but in a way where I can't quite parse your intended meaning...  First, if the Illuminati is changing us via DNA splicing that is not evolution, if it's guided it is not evolution.  There *are* not other evolved forms of homo sapiens besides us and neanderthals, we can't create neanderthals due to lack of their full DNA, and thus there is no other homo sapiens model to choose from.  There are not more evolved Homo Sapien sapiens either, every human is an example of the most evolved sapiens we know

Comment: I think what your asking, throwing out all the talk of evolution  is rather or not a secret society could change humans by intentionally modifying their DNA to create a new form of human, one that has not existed yet?  They can of course create a target Homo Sapiens species and try to use genetic engineering to create something like that targeted creature (not that it would work, but more on that if I can answer this question).  Is that the stated goal of this question?  It's not evolution in any form, so I'm not sure if I understand you correctly...

Answer (score 2):

I think the secret organization is going to have a few problems here'

First off, define what traits that the "new" humans will have that give them an advantage over *H.Sapiens*. We are at the top of the food chain precisely because we are smarter, tougher, more social, more dexterous and more adaptable than any other species. Our Ancestors literally *walked around the world* to settle in habitable places, fought megafauna with pointed sticks and turned objects that other species would ignore into tools. Whatever *N.Sapiens* has will have to be pretty much off the charts to really make inroads into *H.Sapiens*

This leads to issue two: strength in numbers. We are sitting at a manpower advantage of 7 billion to 1 for the home team. We cover all the arable land, usable waterways and indeed virtually every piece of the Earth's surface where it is possible to support life. We will probably be able to physically identify *N.Sapiens* due to physical , mental or emotional features and traits, so can quickly isolate them and physically annihilate them if they are perceived as an existential threat.

Even if they are physically indistinguishable from *H.Sapiens* (they just keep the prehensile tail tucked into the pants and wear sunglasses 24/7 to hide the Anime eyes...) it is quite possible they cannot breed with normal humans, so their genetic material won't "infiltrate" the human population, and their population will be much smaller and have access to far fewer resources than *we* do. They will be outbred and outcompeted on virtually every level once you go beyond one on one competition. If they are too specialized, they might not even win there. (For a funny example, think of how Wesley defeated the three kidnappers in "The Princess Bride").

So from a very limited technical perspective, the secret society can indeed create a new type of human being. If they are very patient, they could even do this the "old fashioned" way by selecting people with the desired traits and offering incentives for them to breed with each other, ensuring the desired traits are isolated from the larger gene pool and constantly reinforced. This seems to have happened to the Ashkenazi Jews, for example. The Ashkenazi's also offer a second lesson; be prepared to ruthlessly cull to prevent undesirable traits from also accumulating. To really make the changes widespread you would have to "release" the breeding stock into the main gene pool every few generations, then restart with a  "higher" baseline, or you will get a regression to the mean.

Genetic engineering isn't quite there yet (we don't really understand how many genes interact or are expressed), but there is no reason to suppose this won't be figured out within a few decades at most. In that case, the "desirable" traits won't be what the secret society wants, but whatever people are willing to pay for.

Answer (score 1):

I’m gonna try to keep this Universe small and say that this is human-on-human action here.

Basically it’s pretty simple from the abstract. Find as may alleles as possible that determine that predatory-intelligence, coupled with alleles that determine sort of slow-and-steady workforce mentalities. Let’s say you are lucky and found 10 alleles each that have 3-5% causal effects of their respective traits.

Weaponize this allele change in a virus. Nothing big or fancy, but have it target the female gametes. Maybe use HPV as a template. Preferably choose something that people don’t know they have, and the more it spreads the better. Release each of your 20 viruses into different regions at different times, once a year. Pair it with some holiday, like thanksgiving or spring break – something when a ton of people travel. Do this for about 50 years.

That generation born will statistically have a couple of the modified alleles. When this generation goes to reproduce, circa 70 years from start, almost every baby will have the chance of having half or so. By 100 years time, every baby born will have a strong disposition for workforce docility.

From there, use the extensive genetic research to find another set of alleles to alter, since you can technically solve human aggression in a fraction of the time given.

Answer (score 0):

Conceivably it is already happening. How would we know?

Much the same idea (without the secret organization part) can be found in Theadora Goss's "Beautiful Boys" http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/beautiful-boys/

She suggests that there exists a group/subspecies/species of beings/humans who seem/are hunky, footloose young men. They arrive in town, work for a while, get a girlfriend, then leave when she's pregnant. Their children turn out good-looking and footloose, too.